What do you see?
Which option A-E should replace ?



I think the answer is

 B

Reasoning

 If we play around with the six given figures (and colour the vertices red for highlighting) we can produce the following

 I think the replacement for the question mark is 'S' to give GRAPHS which would be indicated by two vertices joined by a curve (option B).

Thanks to OP for some clarifying remarks.

Fast! Not the word I had mind, but you got the correct option. I didn't want to answer your question above whether or not it was intentional (at least not so early on) but now can you guess what's ? In the image (the ? Is there :))

@Prim3numbah Ah okay, I get it now, that's very clever, will try to edit

Looks good now, well done!
